# Unable to resolve "missing-asset-registry-path" expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I have an `expo bare workflow` working fine in `SDK 49`. But when I run `expo-doctor` and other solutions, I receive many errors about `gradle` and dependencies.

I've tried to fix it, but many developers with the same problem advised me to create a new project. In my new project, I succeeded with an `expo-doctor` (no issues).

But now I need help with SVG, PNG, and fonts.

> Unable to resolve missing-asset-registry-path from
> node_modules/@expo-google-fonts/poppins/Poppins_100Thin.ttf

I'll receive a PNG or an SVG if I remove Google fonts.

Below is my `package.json`.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@expo-google-fonts/poppins": "^0.2.3",
    "@firebase/firestore": "^4.4.2",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.21",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.23",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.34",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "expo": "~50.0.7",
    "expo-asset": "~9.0.2",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.7.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.5",
    "expo-dev-client": "^3.3.8",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.8.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.7.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "^2.9.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.24.11",
    "firebase": "^10.8.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "phosphor-react-native": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^3.0.7",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.10",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.14.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "1.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "typescript": "^5.3.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
```

I've tried to update all dependencies, downgrade expo, create a new project, but the project has a great complexity to restart everything. I've tried also to remove the pictures and fonts. But the problem persists. Also tried clearing the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm change configs on metro.config.js,added libraries metro-react-native-babel-transformer, babel-plugin-module-resolver

metro.config.js code. For me it solved the problem. Good Luck!

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

const { transformer, resolver } = config;

config.transformer = {
...transformer,
babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
}

config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"],
  };

module.exports = config;
```